# Selecting random number of "where clause" in a MySql query depending upon the choice made out of a given set of checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a Newsletter in which I have the following checkboxes: 
`<input type="checkbox" name="assign[]" value="1" >designation_code_1` 
 
`<input type="checkbox" name="assign[]" value="3" >designation_code_2` 
`<input type="checkbox" name="assign[]" value="4" >designation_code_3` 
`<input type="checkbox" name="assign[]" value="5" >designation_code_4`

I have 2 tables namely `tbl_designations` and `tbl_profile` and below mentioned is the query which i am using to retrieve values from the respective tables.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tbl_designations AS A
        JOIN (
            SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                tbl_profile
            ) AS B
        ON A.is_placement = B.is_placement 
        AND A.designation_code = B.hierarchy 
        AND A.designation_id =5
```

This query gives me 100 records **`each`** which are there corresponding to  **`designation_id = "X"`**
***where X =(1,2,3,4)***

The value of **X** is determined by select the checkboxes above.
If I choose only one checkbox(say first checkbox) then I will get the **`designation_id = 1`**
and the query will fetch records as per the choice/selection of checkbox and gives the desired result.

My doubt is what query should I write so that when I select more than on checkbox at a time then it pulls out the records from the table as per the **choice`(s)`**  made by in the checkbox(means corresponding to the ***values*** of the checkboxes).

I am using `foreach` loop to get the values stored in the **`assign[]`** array.
**Please help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning inquisitive,

you could write something like:

```
... and A.designation_id in (1, 2, 3)
```

The values inside the brackets should be replaces by the values returned from the selected checkboxes.

Comment: Your form should return an array containing the values of the checked checkedboxes. So when you set the values of the boxes to the IDs in the database. The returned array should contain all the ids you want to look at in the database. You can then basically use a for-loop to build a string containing the ids seperated by commas and append that to your query

Comment: well, i have used `implode()` function to send values to `in ('values')` it is working perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

That's silly. Use [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) instead, [joining each element](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) of `$_POST['assign']` with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but when I was editing your post for formatting changes, I couldn't help but see the SQL.

I have rewritten it for you below (You should never use a `select *` as a join - just use the whole table and your database will be *much* happier with you) and you should find better results.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tbl_designations AS A
        JOIN tbl_profile B
        ON A.is_placement = B.is_placement 
        AND A.designation_code = B.hierarchy 
        AND A.designation_id =5
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
where X in (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a comma separated string and use it in the query with a FIND_IN_SET function, e.g. -

```
...
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(X, '1,2,3,4')
```

[FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

Answer (score 0):

for select the random number of columns for each refresh we use this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $Tablename where column = '$bookmark' order by rand() limit 1");
```

:)